# Are there topological invariants for this path-finding game?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, algebraic-topology, hamiltonian-path

There is a game I've seen recently ([link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zerologicgames.findaway&hl=en_US&gl=US); note that I have no affiliation with this game) which involves finding a Hamiltonian path connecting a graph of points, as illustrated below.

[image: blank board] ...... [image: filled board]

The rules are:

- Your starting point is fixed (it is the highlighted dot in the first picture).
- You must form a path connecting all dots on the board, moving only up, down, left or right, and not hitting any dot twice.
- You can't pass through the black squares.
- Typically, the endpoint is fixed as the only dot with valency 1.

Solutions to this game are not unique, but I initially conjectured that they were [path homotopic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(topology)#Homotopy_of_paths) (viewing the paths as embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$ punctured at the locations of the squares).  This turns out to not be true, as the following alternative solution to the above board demonstrates:

[image: alt solution]

**Question: Are there any topological invariants to the solutions of this game?**

Here are two more boards with multiple solutions for reference:

[image: b2] ... [image: b2s1] ... [image: b2s2]

[image: b3] ... [image: b3s1] ... [image: b3s2]

Comment: "Typically, **both** endpoints are 1-valent."  Also, every solution is isotopic to an embedded interval, so all solutions are isotopic, hence homotopic.  You might find what you want in https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-applied-mathematics/volume-2012/issue-none/Hamiltonian-Paths-in-Some-Classes-of-Grid-Graphs/10.1155/2012/475087.full or in its references.

Comment: @EricTowers I meant homotopic with endpoints fixed.

Comment: @EricTowers I'm also not sure what you mean by your opening quote.

Comment: You state "Typically, the endpoint is fixed as the only dot with valency 1."  Both endpoints are 1-valent.

Comment: You say nothing about homotopy relative to fixed endpoints.

Comment: @EricTowers Ah, I see.  Regarding valency, I meant on the underlying graph.  Clearly both endpoints are 1-valent on the path, but they are not so on the graph (see the pictures for examples).  And for the homotopy thing, see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(topology)#Homotopy_of_paths  Since this is apparently unclear, I will make some edits to clarify.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120904/discussion-between-yly-and-eric-towers).

Comment: In the first row of your "two more boards", the given endpoint is 2-valent in the underlying graph and the solution's **other** endpoint is 1-valent.  The 2-valency of the given endpoint is explicitly used to give two distinct solutions.

Comment: "Typically, the endpoint is fixed as the only dot with valency 1" should be read (and maybe restated in the question) as "The end of the path is not given, but typically, it can be deduced, because the underlying graph has a vertex of degree 1 which cannot be an intermediate point of the path."